# Issue with Quadratic Formula

Tags: python-2.7, quadratic

The following code is what I'm using for a quadratic problem solver, where a cannot equal 0. I am currently getting really odd answers, and can't seem to figure out the problem. Thoughts?

```
def descriminant(a, b, c): #Setting input perameters for descriminant
if a>0 or a<0: #If a isnt equal to 0, find descriminant
    disc = (b**2-4*a*c) #Defining what descriminant does with disc
    if disc>0:
        disc1=float(disc)**0.5
        return disc1 #returns and allows to be used again instead of print which doesnt allow you to use it again

    else:
        print("The discriminant must be greater than 0")
else: #if a is equal to 0
    print ("A cannot equal 0") #Tell the user a cant equal 0


def quad_form(a, b, c): #Defining quad form w/ input a, b, c

disc2=float(descriminant(a, b, c))


quad_form1=((-1*b) + disc2/float((2*a))) #Defining + forumula for quad form
quad_form2=((-1*b) - disc2/float((2*a))) #Defining - forumula for quad form

return quad_form1, quad_form2


UI=input("Enter the coefficients of a quadratic separated by commas where A is not equal to zero: ") #User Input
a=float(UI[0])
b=float(UI[1])
c=float(UI[2])

print quad_form(a, b, c)
```

Comment: What are the expected answers and what are the actual answers? Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're taking square root twice. Once in `discriminant()` and then in `quad_form()`. You should remove one of them.

EDIT:
Your `quad_form` expressions are also wrong:

```
quad_form1=((-1*b) + disc3/float((2*a)))
```

should be

```
quad_form1=((-1*b) + disc3)/float((2*a))
```

or more readably

```
quad_form1=(-b + disc3)/float(2*a).
```

Similarly for the next line,

```
quad_form1=((-1*b) - disc3)/float((2*a))
```

Comment: This better @Aditya Kashi ? I don't get the right answer still

Comment: Just directly use disc2 in the formula. Don't cast it to `int`. Also, are the user's inputs necessarily integers? In either case, you should make a,b and c `float` instead of `int`.

Comment: Ok I made those Changes, but it doesn't seem to help with the output. The numbers just aren't correct, i have used online calculators and done it myself @Aditya Kashi

Comment: Check the placements of brackets in your formulae. See the edit.